# Como receber data de usuário através do JTextField, usando o JodaTime?

Tags: java, swing, jodatime

Não estou conseguindo fazer a entrada do usuário. Quero que o programa faça a diferença de dias entre a data de hoje e a data digitada pelo usuário. O programa possui mais implementações mas é apenas essa parte que não está dando certo.

```
private JTextField dataVencimento;
dataVencimento = new JTextField(20)
container.add(dataVencimento);

...

DateTime hoje = new DateTime();
DateTime dataVencimento = new DateTime();

Days daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(dataVencimento, hoje);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dias de diferença: " + daysBetween, 
                     "Atraso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente efetuar esta conta usando [**`LocalDate`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), fazendo o parse da string com [**`DateTimeFormatter`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
  String strDate = "30/08/2016";
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
  LocalDate dataVencimento = LocalDate.parse(strDate, formatter);

  LocalDate dataHoje = LocalDate.now();

  long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dataHoje, dataVencimento);

  System.out.println(daysBetween);
```

O código acima, se executado hoje(31/07/2016), vai exibir 30. Se der negativo, é porque a segunda data é menor que a primeira data passada no `DAYS.between`.

Veja funcionando no **[ideone](https://ideone.com/nrKY1p)**.

**Referências**:

[Java SE 8 Date and Time(oracle)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html)

[Calculate days between two dates in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27006098/5524514)

Answer (score 0):

Valeu aí diegofm, sua resposta foi útil, embora eu tenho conseguido resolver de outro modo, foi apenas uma questão de lógica mesmo.

```
private JTextField dia;
private JTextField mes;
private JTextField ano;

container.add(new JLabel("Dia"));
container.add(dia);
container.add(new JLabel("Mês"));
container.add(mes);
container.add(new JLabel("Ano"));
container.add(ano);

...

int day = Integer.parseInt(dia.getText());
int month = Integer.parseInt(mes.getText());
int year = Integer.parseInt(ano.getText());

DateTime hoje = new DateTime();
DateTime dataVencimento = new DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0);

Days diferenca = Days.daysBetween(dataVencimento, hoje);
```

O que eu fiz foi criar uma variável para cada parte da data, dia, mês, ano, e converter para um inteiro e colocar a variável dentro do DateTime dataVencimento.

Comment: Você também pode usar um `JFormattedTextField`, com uma máscara que permita apenas o formato de data, e usar o método que sugeri, creio que fica até melhor do que ter que usar 3 componentes. Você vai ter que validar os 3 para chegar se a algum valor invalido foi passado, ou se o campo está vindo em branco. Com o componente que citei, você faz isso apenas uma vez. outra opção é usar o componente `JCalendar`, que já faz isso tudo para você.

Comment: É verdade, preciso validar cada um, sem contar que fica chato três entradas ao invés de apenas uma. Mais um vez valeu.